# Is it possible to programmatically send a picture in Messenger under my own user name?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, messenger

I'd like to write a script which, when run, will run some program which creates a `.jpg` file, and then I'd like to send that as an image message over Facebook Messenger to a given user.

Note that my use case is a matter of simple automation. This should all happen under my own user ID, i.e. it would be using my user access token, I would be sending the message to a Messenger group that my user is already a member of, etc. So this is not a question about making a Facebook app that would be accessible to others; the context is strictly behaving as my own user ID.

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: @WizKid how about with browser automation?

Comment: They only way Facebook allows you to interact with them is the API.